# Custom Post Type: Upload Multiple Images

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

So I'm making this Property Listing theme for a client of mine, and on the Properties Custom Post Type (CPT) which I have created I need to add a meta box that allows him to upload multiple pictures - something similar to this:

[image: Upload Meta Box]

How could I do this? Everything I have seen so far recommends plugins like Advanced Custom Fields but I would like to avoid using 3rd party Plugins if I can.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you these videos --> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIjMj0-5C8TJYSkKnUyHH1VXlIpvZXOMT

In my opinion I prefer use the plugin ACF. The plugin helps to save time. It's easy to use and the client will be happy. Also, the client won't care if you used a plugin or you wrote the code by yourself, the client will care if the functionality works.

I am the first in not installing plugins but ACF plugin is necessary (mandatory). I use it in all my projects.

Comment: I know some others who disagree with ACF ;) I know what ACF is and does but personally I'd prefer to learn more about the WordPress CodeX and how to do things without a Plugin - but then again that's just personal preference and everyone is different :) Thanks for that link I will take a look into it when I can

Comment: ACF is a plugin and if you create that functionality, to create a custom image uploader, you will have to create a plugin so... you will have to have a plugin for that, your won plugin or ACF. I guess... you can not do it writing two or three lines in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Add a security object for file uploads like so:

```
class FileSecure
{
    public resource $Allowed;
    private object $Info;
    public function __construct($allow)
    {
        $this->Allowed = $allow;    
        $this->Info = new finfo();
    }
    public function Check($file) : bool
    {
        if(in_array($fileType = $this->Info->file($file, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $this->Allowed))) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }
}

$fileCheck = array(
     'Image' => new FileSecure(['image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png']),
     'Text' => new FileSecure(['text/plain']),
     'Compressed' => new FileSecure(['application/zip', 'application/x-rar-compressed'])
);
```

[Click here to view all the MIME name's to extensions](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list)

Then add a front-end form which allows file upload and just pass it through this object before use of the uploaded file.

```
// note it must exist on the server before checking
if(!$fileCheck['Image']->Check($filename)):
    // delete the file
endif;
```

You could use the Database to hold file locations or just have a default upload directory on your server and iterate through the files held within that directory.

Comment: Shall I make a Plugin to do this? Will it be used in more than one Project?